# Form action tel not working in Chrome on Android?

Tags: html, forms, tel

```
<form action="tel:0123456789" method="get">
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
<a href="tel:0123456789">call</a>
```

In the Android Stock Browser and iOS Safari both the form and the link trigger a phone call but in Chrome on Android only the link works.

Is this a bug and is there a way around it?

Comment: and if you remove the method="link" ?

Comment: iam not sure if method="link" exist... i think it will use method="get". if u want hyperlink looks like button then u should use css

Comment: Sorry, method="link" is not supposed to be there. Changed it to "get" and also tried without any method at all. Still the same problem.

Comment: And what this form should do? If u want trigger call u dont need form

Comment: It should trigger a call and it needs to be a form since it's using an external script which requires a form element. Most of all I'm perplexed though why this simple action is not working in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use this html

```
<form id ="form1">
     <a href="tel:numberInInternationalFormat"><button>Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

Then use this javascript

```
<script>
$("#form1").on('submit',(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

I encountered this issue and got rid of the form entirely since it wasnt pertinent to the functionality of my code, but since yours is, you can work with this